# view pdf file in browser from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, phpmyadmin

I am trying to retrieve pdf files stored in a mysql database and display them in the browser. When the view button is clicked, it is displaying an error: `failed to load pdf document`.

My code is as follows:

```
 $query=  mysql_query("SELECT uploaded_file FROM pdf_file where id='2'");
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header("Content-type: application/pdf");
 header('Content-disposition:inline; filename="'.$query.'"');
 @read($query);
```

In the above code, when the view button is clicked, a file id is passed.

Comment: Is `uploaded_file` the file name - ie. `file.pdf` - or is it the actual file?

Comment: Did you really write `$query` in `header('Content-disposition:inline; filename="'.$query.'"');`? if so then you must not get the file, because mysql_query gives you only resource, to get result you have to use `mysql_fetch_assoc($query)` or any.

Comment: it is the actual file

Comment: The mysql extension is depreciated. It's advised to use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the result set....

```
$result=  mysql_query("SELECT uploaded_file FROM pdf_file where id='2'");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
$file = $row['uploaded_file'];
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
@read($file);
```

Also - i'm not sure why you're want to use content-disposition inline. You could just go as follows to display inline:

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
@read($file);
```

Comment: and another thing - mysql_query is deprecated... see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I tryed with mysql_fetch_row but still it is showing failed to load pdf file

Comment: what's in the parameter $file? and is $result equal to true? If not your query is incorrect, possibly because of id='2' instead of id=2 or something

Comment: i see you write that the result really returned the right filename, in that case there's a problem with your headers - 0 see corrections in my response

Comment: Actually i was not able view pdf because my download ide was on when i gave exit it redirected to pdf format but still it shows error message  Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF "http://localhost/pdfupload/viewpdf.php".

Answer (score 0):

Ok so why not save the actual FILE in a directory and save the location to the file in the database. Then just call the file reference from the database and the browser will open it if you have adobe installed in your browser. Think that might be easing then saving it as a blob.